# best coding platform to integrate with django application

Tags: django, api, integration, web-ide

We have one application developed in django framework, Now I wanted to have a coding platform/IDE wherein I'll be giving problem statement and user will write code, compile and run to get the solution. Once he submits that code it has to pass the testcases passed by me(or throw the errors, if any). Finally I should get result of problem statement.

Is there any third party coding IDE/platform to be integrated with my application(be it open-source/paid) along with all testcases? I've searched for and found judge0,hacker earth APIs which are the compilers by which we could send source code and get output of it which doesn't fulfill my requirements though. Please share if any suggestions/recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Think of using spoj online editor https://www.spoj.com/sphereengine/